# Three.js starting and stopping a simple mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am still new to Three.js and WebGL but I want to get better at it. Could you please check my code having found a solution to a fairly simple problem that I set for myself.

SIMPLE PROBLEM (that took too long to solve):
How can I animate a simple 400 x 400 PLANE MESH from y position 500 (below browser window) to x,y,z position 0 (centre of the browser window) - WITHOUT using Tween.js? I know Tween.js for Three.js is very efficient for simple movements but I wanted to find a solution that involves learning. Use Tween.js and I don't learn anything. And yes, I did hours of research looking at various solutions on StackOverflow and on Mr Doob's code repository on GitHub. After very extensive searching, I couldn't find a solution that gave me exactly what I wanted, namley: A simple vertical upward animation STARTING out of frame AND STOPPING in the centre of the browser window.

MY SOLUTION:

```
      `function animate() {
      var newPos = plane.position.y;
      plane.translateY( 4 );
      function stopHere () {
          if (newPos >= 0)
          {
              plane.position.set( 0, 0, 0);
              var stopPlane = plane.position.y = 0;
          }
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(stopHere);
    }

    function render() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        animate();
    }`
```

I've posted just the two functions that do all the work. Does anyone see bad practice there? My logic is that

`requestAnimationFrame`

cannot be in the render(); function, as it needs to be within the scope of the nested function ('stopHere') within

```
  `animate();`
```

I ran into difficulty approaching it from this direction:

```
 `objMesh.geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 1, 0.1, 0.1 ) ); `
```

After wrestling with something simple for over a week, I just know it works. To my understanding, I have used a method of the applyMatrix sub-class and made it work. I'm asking for comments because I want to learn Three.js, not bad habits. Please, does anyone see bad practice or bad coding?  Many thanks.

ksqInFlight

Comment: You may get a better answer on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or possibly [Game Dev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I am a senior citizen, so my approach is, in your requestAnimationFrame loop:

```
function fnloop() {
  var dy = Math.min(Math.abs(plane.position.y), .01); // max movement
  if (Math.abs(dy) >= .000001) {
    if (plane.position.y > 0) dy = -dy; // move down if above
    plane.position.y += dy; // move up or down
    if (Math.abs(plane.position.y) < .000001) alert("Done!");
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(fnloop);  
}
```